# Expect call with the exact object instance as argument

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    int state;
};

class SomeClass
{
    virtual MyClass myFunction1() = 0;
    virtual void myFunction2(MyClass) = 0;
};

class MyMock : public SomeClass
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD0(myFunction1, MyClass());
    MOCK_METHOD1(myFunction2, void(MyClass));
};

TEST_F(/* ... */)
{
    MyMock myMock;
    MyClass myObject;
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction1()).WillOnce(Return(myObject));
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction2(myObject));
}
```

When I wrote this code I thought I was testing if `myFunction2` was using the exact instance of `MyClass` returned by `myFunction1`. But this code also passes:

```
TEST_F(/* ... */)
{
    MyMock myMock;
    MyClass myObject1;
    MyClass myObject2;
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction1()).WillOnce(Return(myObject1));
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction2(myObject2));
}
```

So apparently the 2nd `EXPECT_CALL()` only checks if `myFunction2` is called with any `MyClass` object that has the same value as `myObject2` and not if it's the same instance which might also be a valid test but it tests a different (more general?) behavior.

How can I check if it's the same instance?

Comment: What is MyClasss? What is SomeClass?

Comment: @n.m. Are you asking if they're POD or non-POD? Or is there more to it?

Comment: I'm askung to provide a [mcve]. Please take guessing completely out of the game.

Comment: your functions do not return references or pointers, but copies. you can't check for the same instance if you return and pass by value. your test will invoke the comparison operator and checks if `myObject1 == myObject2`.

Comment: @fdan is right. If you `myFunction2` must get the result of 'myFunction1' it must either throw an exception or return an error. Also, this quite a strange design decision. Maybe we have XY problem here?

Comment: @fdan Looks like your comment should be an answer. Also, to check for concrete instance do I have to return a reference from `myFunction1` or pass by reference in `myFunction2`?

Comment: @NPS You `myFunction2` require return from `myFunction1`. It doesn't make any sense. Obviously, you tried to solve some other problem and came up with this solution. But test revealed design flaw - you have no way to enforce correct function call... Moreover, this API can be easily used incorrectly. So it's hard to answer w/o information about the reason for such API. So, it is an XY problem.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko No, it's not. In my original code these methods belong to different classes. But that's not important to my question so for simplicity (and in order to provide less code to analyze) I put them in the same class. If people here focused more on what someone is actually asking and less on trying to convince them they shouldn't do that in the first place, we wouldn't be having this discussion right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from my previous comment: your functions do not use references/pointers, but a copy (therefore it's not possible to compare the address of both copies). `myFunction1` and `myFunction2` both have to use references/pointers in order to do the comparison. The following example tests your initial setup.

```
class SomeClass
{
    virtual MyClass* myFunction1() = 0; // pointer!
    virtual void myFunction2(MyClass*) = 0; // pointer!
};

TEST_F(/* ... */)
{
    MyMock myMock;
    MyClass myObject;
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction1()).WillOnce(Return(&myObject)); // dereference!
    EXPECT_CALL(myMock, myFunction2(&myObject)); // dereference!
}
```